# Threading in Eclipse 

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How can we create a separate thread to perform an operation until it is stopped (using say, a button) in Eclipse? I read that you need to use `asyncExec()` function (because I need the UI to be updated simultaneously). But for some reason, the `Display` class is not recognized in my IDE.

Comment: `Display` is part of `org.eclipse.swt` - is the SWT plugin setup as a dependency of your project?

Answer (score 2):

You should read this tutorial: [Eclipse Jobs and Background Processing](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html). The website also has a lot of good tutorials for other eclipse-related topics.